# reactjs not re-rendering in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my code, whenever I call a `setState` it seems like it is indeed changing the state but it is not being reflected in the browser. Here is my function that calls setState. This function deletes an element from an array called `rows1` in my state:

```
removeFromRowsById = index => {
   console.log("IN REMOVE FUNCTION");


   const newList = [...this.state.rows1];
   newList.splice(index, 1);
   this.setState({ rows1: newList });
};
```

Here is part of my render method where I use the contents of `rows1`.

```
 return (
  <Paper className={classes.root}>
    <EnhancedTableToolbar numSelected={selected.length} />
    <div className={classes.tableWrapper}>
      {console.log("UPDATED ARRAY:", rows1)} //I PRINT IT HERE
      <Table className={classes.table} aria-labelledby="tableTitle">
        <EnhancedTableHead
          rows={rows1} //I USE IT HERE
          order={order}
          orderBy={orderBy}
          onRequestSort={this.handleRequestSort}
        />
         ......
```

Notice where I log `rows1` before I assign `rows` to it. In the console, at first it prints `rows1` without the deleted value, and than after the state has changed I guess, it re-renders and prints `rows1` with the deleted value, meaning there is one less items in the list which is good. The problem is, this is not being reflected in the browser. It's like as though nothing changes

**NOTE**: When I copy the value of `rows1` after the change, and assign `rows` to it, it properly reflects it so I know I'm assigning the proper variable. How do I fix this issue.

The only way I can get around this is by adding a boolean in the callback of `removeFromRowsById` and setting it to true once the state is updated. And than I'd need to only return in the render method when the condition is true, otherwise I return something else. I don't think that's the proper way to do it though because it should re-render properly with the new value of `rows1` but it seems like it keeps the old value assigned to `row`. Please share your thoughts with me and let me know if things are unclear. I didn't want to post my whole code because it's pretty long.

Comment: It may be because you need to use the 2nd form of `setState()` to handle async issues. Please try checking the official ReactJS guide's [setState may be asynchronus](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous) if it helps.

Comment: @jonathangersam I did it in the second form and I'm still getting the same behaviour... this is how I set the state: `this.setState((state) => ({
      rows1: newList
    }));`

Comment: @jonathangersam so it still updates `rows1` but it doesn't appear to render it

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was passing `rows1` to a property inside of `EnhancedTableHead` as you can see in the original. So since I was doing this, `rows` inside of `EnhancedTableHead` wasn't being updated after `setState`because I was using state inside my render method like this: `const { rows } = this.state;` instead props, which is was it should've been like this `const { rows } = this.props;`.

Hope that helps someone in the future!